# Linking Issue - Symbol not found

Tags: swift, cocoapods, dyld, dji-sdk

I recently upgraded my project by updating the djisdk cocoa pods pull to the latest version, and when I did my app still compiled (after making a few adjustments to the way I was interfacing with the camera), but upon running the app, it immediately fails upon load with the following crash:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _DJIFlightControllerParamRTKBaseStationLatitude
Referenced from: /Users/devguy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47DA5958-DCAF-46B7-9ABB-DBBF59F82764/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4C6FFFEE-0267-4CA2-B073-37BA493DC282/DJICameraAssist.app/Frameworks/DJIUILibrary.framework/DJIUILibrary
Expected in: /Users/devguy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47DA5958-DCAF-46B7-9ABB-DBBF59F82764/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4C6FFFEE-0267-4CA2-B073-37BA493DC282/DJICameraAssist.app/Frameworks/DJISDK.framework/DJISDK
in /Users/devguy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/47DA5958-DCAF-46B7-9ABB-DBBF59F82764/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4C6FFFEE-0267-4CA2-B073-37BA493DC282/DJICameraAssist.app/Frameworks/DJIUILibrary.framework/DJIUILibrary
(lldb)
```

I realize that this is likely just a linking issue, and not a problem with the code itself, but given that the only change to the DJI libraries was through the cocoa pods update, I'm not even sure where to start.

I've tried all of the following so far with no success:

- Manually linking the DJISDK and DJI UI libraries
- Uninstalling the DJI libraries using a pod uninstall, then re-installing them.

My podfile DJI section:

```
pod 'DJI-SDK-iOS', '~> 4.5.1’
pod 'DJI-UILibrary-iOS', '~> 4.4’
```

Any additional ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the UX SDK (Formally known as DJI UILibrary). You should make sure the versions are always the same in Major.Minor.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The documentation is really bad with regards to highlighting deprecated libraries.  I've actually been using the UI documentation on the DJI website, but somehow, I ended up on the UI library, which never references the UX library, and the pod instructions were actually copied verbatim from the UI library pages.  I hope there are more prominent notes on their old libraries soon.  I appreciate you pointing me to the correct SDK!

Comment: I know -- and it's appreciated.  It's already 1000% better than it was 12 months ago.  The samples are getting better, too.  I'm not having to translate near as much from objective-c to swift, and that's appreciated, as well!